# Check if one array is greater than another

Tags: java, algorithm

Given two integer arrays A and B, return true iff. for every integer in A there is a greater integer in B. There needs to be a 1 to 1 mapping, each integer in A has to find its own greater integer in B.

Example:

```
int[] A = {1, 1, 5, 3};
int[] B = {7, 5, 2, 3};
boolean result = isGreater(A,B); 

/* 
result is true because:

A[0] < B[2], 
A[1] < B[3],
A[2] < B[0], 
A[3] < B[1].

Every integer in A found its greater integer in B. Note that multiple mappings can exist,
finding one is enough to return true.
*/
```

My current solution is O(n^2), I iterate B for every element in A. Is there a better way?

Comment: Sort both arrays and iterate over both sorted arrays at the same time.  Should be `O(n log n)`.

Answer (score 4):

You can do it in O(n logn).

1. Sort both the lists - O(n logn)
2. Use a routine *similar*<sup>1</sup> to the `merge` routine of Merge sort to walk through both arrays trying to find its greater integer partner - O(n)

---

<sup>1</sup> In merge routine from Merge sort, we compare two numbers (one from each array) pointed to by two running indexes and pick the smaller (or the larger) number and store it in a new array and move the index from which we picked the element by one. But here, there *has to* be a one-one mapping.

Comment: @Socowi it's not lexicographical comparison, consider the following 2 arrays after sorting: [1, 15], [2, 3]. by lexicographical comparison, the second is larger than the first, yet it doesn't fit the description of the algorithm.

Comment: @M.Aroosi Maybe it makes sense for an element pair and that's what I thought from Socowi's comment.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a Java 8+ implementation of the algorithm described by [user7](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49263497/5743988):

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

public static boolean isGreater(int[] a, int[] b) {
    if (b.length < a.length) {
        return false;
    }
    final int[] sortedA = Arrays.stream(a).sorted().toArray();
    final int[] sortedB = Arrays.stream(b).sorted().toArray();
    return IntStream.range(0, a.length).allMatch(i -> sortedA[i] < sortedB[i]);
}
```

[Ideone Demo](https://ideone.com/HAThfQ)

Comment: What would you do if you had to return the maximal possible number of matches?

Comment: @AnnaVopureta I would use a `for` loop instead of an `IntStream`, and I would use a separate index variable for accessing `sortedB` that only increases when a match is found. When the end of either array is reached, return the current index for `sortedB`.

Answer (score 0):

you could look at bucket sort:

> Bucket sort, or bin sort, is a sorting algorithm that works by
>   distributing the elements of an array into a number of buckets. Each
>   bucket is then sorted individually, either using a different sorting
>   algorithm, or by recursively applying the bucket sorting algorithm.

However, if you do both bucket sorts at the same time, merging buckets, you don't need to sort some buckets if there are already enough elements in other larger buckets. so we can save some time in the average case.

Also you could use selection sort within each bucket, to get the K largest items within a bucket say, if the other corresponding bucket had only K items.

Answer (score 0):

a simple

```
Arrays.compare(b,a)
```

will do the job. if array b>=a in every element it will return 1 otherwise it will return -1

Comment: What if I want to check for only b > a